# Automatically run debugging code every time a function is entered (perhaps by altering the "Function" prototype object?)

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I'm trying to achieve the following functionality:

Every time I call a function, an Alert window to pop (before doing what that function is supposed to do) telling me what function was called and eventually some more data (like who or what “this” is, who called me, etc.) While this can be easily done in C++, I cannot seem to find the “Function” structure (members/methods) detailed anywhere. Needless to say google-ing it was at no benefit.

While I managed to add a member to “Function”, and this member do exists in any function created afterwards, I'm far off intended functionality.

This is what I have done:

```
Function.prototype.demo= function (){ alert("I'm on every function!")}
function x(){alert("whatever")}
x.demo() // alerts the "I'm on every function!" message
```

This is what I would need:

```
Function.prototype.FIRST_TO_BE_RAN=function(){alert("useful info here about me")}
function x(){alert("whatever")};
x();// first the “useful info here about me” to be displayed, then the “whatever”
```

How could I do that and a link to the Function object manual/documentation would be appreciated.

Comment: "While this can be easily done in C++" - how would you do it in C++? I don't know of any way, so there's probably something you're allowing solutions to do that I'm not considering.

Comment: ...there are multiple ways to do that in C++: the most basic, using the class constructor for displaying whatever at the "construct event", using pointers to functions to "serialize" execution of custom functions/dynamic functions before other function, creating array-style of pointer functions for achieving the dynamic execution and so on and so forth to the most exotic like machine-code address overriding...

Comment: @write2july: so you can also use constructors in javascript.

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want to intercept every function call without "configuring" the interceptor for every function explicitly?

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking: altering the prototype or the parent or the constructor of Function object.... but I could not find in the last 2 days any manual regarding the Function object-prototype. I do not know what or who it inherits, or it's members...

Comment: @try-catch-finally - not intercept but alter/change the prototype used to create every function in JS, so that every function does "something"-the same thing...

Comment: @zerkms: I could use a "constructor" to customize my own code (functions or "objects") but that would have (maybe) the desired effect ONLY on my own functions, not on the JS predefined functions.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to do that? E.g. if it for some kind of coverage test?

Comment: @write2july: Those C++ solutions all require some sort of modification to either the definition or the use of each function. That's quite different from what you're trying to do here, which is one piece of code that affects every function in the entire program.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to do what you are trying to do in JavaScript.

If you are willing to re-write/uglify some of your code, you could change all instances of:

```
var z = myFunctionCall(a, b, c);
```

to

```
var z = myFunctionCall.call(null, a, b, c);
```

then you can overwrite `Function.prototype.call` but I haven't tested that in every browser.

Another option, depending on your code base, is to use your editor tools to search-and-replace every instance of

```
function <name>(<arguments>) <whitespace> { <whitespace>
```

with

```
function <name>(<arguments>) <whitespace> { <whitespace> alert("Entering function <name");
```

There will still be a lot of manual cleanup though.

When debugging an IE extension that didn't return function names or line numbers in any of the error messages, the second approach is what I took.

Answer (score -1):

So I do not have the solution but here's the high level concept that i think shall work.

I change the Function prototype to become

Function wrapper instead

so Function { a,b,c,d .... }

is now Wrapper Function(reachable as 'Function' call { Function {a,b,c,d .... } and PreFunction {the common pre functionality ... } }

Each function call actually meets Function preCall, which does the common stuff and then redirects to the actual Function call

whichever the language what we need is the Controller pattern(as vaguely described above) .